# Can IronPython be used on Windows IoT Python Background Application?

Tags: c#, python, iot

When writing a Windows 10 IoT app using Python, is it possible to switch the implementation of the interpreter from CPython to IronPython (if it is not already IronPython - I do not have a Raspberry Pi to test this on)?

My goal is to use IronPython to execute C# code, so that I can use both Python and C# in my app.

If there is another way to do this, then please let me know.